# MVC3 IsValid and Business Logic Layer

Tags: validation, asp.net-mvc-3, business-logic

I am using MVC3 for my application and I have a question about validation.  I have a Business Logic layer that is separate from my web layer where I will have a function like CreateUser, which creates a new user for the application to use.  I want this function to be accessible in two places:  1)  Somewhere in a controller that makes use of it and 2) in a "Setup Data" program that inserts data into the system.

I want to make use of things like `ModelState.IsValid` to check for all basic validation, but this won't help me for my Setup Data mode (or any other mode that doesn't go through MVC).  Is there any way I can still leverage this code, but to contain all validation in my BusinessLogic layer instead of in the controller without having the BusinessLogic layer rely on MVC?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like [this article about Service Layers has what I need](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/validating-with-a-service-layer-cs).  Other suggestions are still welcome.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the article on service layers still means that you need a dependency on the MVC assembly.  After wrestling a bit with this myself recently, I'm now of the opinion that keeping things as separate as possible is a good design.  In my model assembly, I have a services folder wherein from, say, a Create() routine, I validate and throw custom exceptions.

The service layer doesn't care who or how these exceptions are consumed.  In your MVC app, map them into model state errors collections or whatever.  Your design is all the more solid because your model assembly doesn't depend on some validation runner making appropriate use of MVC validation attributes, collections, etc.

I also noticed the article mentions a repository.  I know it's all the rage these days but if you're already using an ORM like Entity Framework, a repository is really just a [DAO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_access_object).  [Reposity is the new Singleton](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBoQFjAA&url=http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2009/04/17/repository-is-the-new-singleton.aspx&rct=j&q=repository%20is%20the%20new%20singleton&ei=cMvCTfPqO8XFgAfcoY3eAQ&usg=AFQjCNHwFYppTJfTeQNBD1_FN44pc-W1JQ&cad=rja).

Comment: later in the article he abstracts away MVC so that the service layer just takes an interface so it is not directly tied to MVC (if I am reading it correctly).

Comment: You are absolutely reading it correctly.  I didn't read to the end before I left my comment (a common personal failing I must admit).  Just make sure you don't end up with a bunch of one line services.